# How to stop Admin panel Access from Production Server

Tags: php, wordpress, iis

I have word-press website on my production server and i want to stop the access of admin panel from production server.

```
e.g WWW.live.com\WP-admin // want to stop open this panel from live server
```

If i change some thing from staging server , so how i can Synchronize the Data and plugins from staging Server to Live Server (Production Server).

Answer (score 0):

You can change the path of wp-admin to prevent it from accessing.Here is a plugin for your use

https://wordpress.org/plugins/hc-custom-wp-admin-url/